# How to check sd card file system

Tags: android, adb, android-sdcard, android-file

I try to run file system check on my sd card.
I opened adb shell and run the following command:

```
/system/bin $ fsck_msdos -f /mnt/extSdCard
```

I get the following error:

```
** /mnt/extSdCard (NO WRITE)
Invalid signature in boot block: 00002|shell@android:/system/bin
```

I use Cyanogen mod 10.1 on Galaxy S2.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may need to unmount it first. See http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/check-and-fix-sd-card-errors-within-android-itself and it looks like your question is an off topic :)

Comment: Don't fsck the mount point, fsck the device itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chris Stratton suggested: Don't fsck the mount point, fsck the device itself
As shoe rat said, I found the answer here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/check-and-fix-sd-card-errors-within-android-itself